# Solr commit failing after indexing

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

i am working on project that creates customized forms for data collection, these data can range from textual to multimedia.

> - i am using solr version 7.5.0 to index data, running in standalone mode.

---

Sometimes while indexing data it gives 200 response. but fails after commit is done.

- Success Response

```
 "responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "QTime":2}}
```

- Failed Response

```
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 57
  },
  "error": {
    "metadata": [
      "error-class",
      "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class",
      "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
    ],
    "msg": "Exception writing document id a0e1825c-85d7-4838-97e6-468a2e4d3315_8c524d4169a84efabd2ab386908c6b2e to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change DocValues type from NUMERIC to SORTED_NUMERIC for field \"date_field\"",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

---

Command used to index data

```
'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update/json/docs? 
commitWithin=1000&split=/|/form_fields/',
headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(json_data))
```

---

**Solutions tried**

> 1."commit=true" while indexing data
>       - data is not available for searching and takes alot of time to be display
>
> 2."commit=false" while indexing data
>       - data is not indexed,and have to manually index all documents

So my concern is there any way, that i can find the commit fail issue of that particular document by some unique id or just flush bad documents before commit if it is going to fail while indexing

Comment: That error message is telling you that a field that was previously indexed as non-multivalued has now been set to multivalued - i.e. that the `date_field` definition has previously been indexed with a different definition to what it's defined as now.